# jQuery : If condition working but how to check result in all the if conditions

Tags: jquery, if-statement

My problem is in this part of the code. I need both of these conditions to be checked for different cases.

```
       if(!printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation()){
            return false;
        }
        else if(!optionfucntions.engravingValidation()){
            return false;
        }
```

It only check the first condition always.
I have also tried like this

```
      if(!printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation()){
            return false;
        }

         if(!optionfucntions.engravingValidation()){
            return false;
        }
```

This is the code for `#button-add click`

```
  $('#button-add').on('click', function() {
    //.product-info select
    //ajax_price();

    if($(".engravingDropDown option:selected").attr('data-engraving') == 'No Engraving') {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
    /* change button text depend on options selection */
    if($('#myOptions').is(':has(span)') === true){

        $('#select-options').text('REVIEW OR EDIT OPTIONS AND ACCESSORIES');


    }else{

        $('#select-options').text('SELECT AVAILABLE OPTIONS AND ACCESSORIES');
    }
    <?php if($showCustomizeBook){ ?>
    $('#customizeBookCustomPriceText').show();
    <?php } ?>
    if(!printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation()){
        return false;
    }
    else if(!optionfucntions.engravingValidation()){
        return false;
    }
    checkDropdownToSetButtonvalue();
    $('.selectMandatoryOption').hide().text('');
});
```

**Update :**

I have different products in my website for which different options in a dropdown are available for customers to choose.
One type of products have `engraving fonts` with fonts options  Narkisim, cherokee etc. If user does select any font there appears an input field in which user needs to write some text to be printed. If user selects a font let say `narkisim` and does not enter some text and clicks `#button-add` it should not allow it to add without adding some text.
Other type of products have `Name to be printed` with options  outside the book, inside the book or no name. If user does select an option there appears an input field in which user needs to write some text to be printed. If user selects an option let say `inside the book` and does not enter some text and clicks `#button-add` it should not allow it to add without adding some text.
I hope that makes sense now?

**Update 2 :**

**for product with print option**

```
console.log(printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation())
```

it returns false

```
console.log(optionfucntions.engravingValidation())
```

it returns true

**for product with engraving option**

```
console.log(printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation())
```

it returns true

```
console.log(optionfucntions.engravingValidation())
```

it returns false

Comment: Unless I wrongly understand your need, merely suppressing the `else` between your two `if()` (like in your 2nd attempt) will work. This way the two last statements are executed only if both conditions are true.

Comment: @cFreed that is not correct. the `return false;` in the first check makes the else statement completely superfluous. The effect would be the same with or without it

Comment: @cFreed Sir it does not work. Check the update for the question

Comment: @DelightedD0D Oops, you're right! I didn't pay attention enough, and the `else` is merely useless. So I wonder what the OP wants really...

Comment: @Mehar44 Yes it doesn't work, my bad (see my previous comment). But with your edit I don't understand your need any more. Please elaborate: what do you actually want to happen in each of the cases? And more important: what is currently not happening like expected?

Comment: @cFreed I have a hunch the real issue might be in `printnameValidation()`. It seems like `printnameValidation()` may be always returning `false` and the OP doesnt realize it. That seems like the only thing that would cause the behaviour here

Comment: I don't exactly know the behavior of the code. I am working on someone else's code. Let me take some more time to understand it, then I will update here.

Comment: @Mehar44 by *behaviour* I simply mean the fact that the you're saying the second check *never* gets called. That could only happen if `printnameValidation()` always returns 'false'

Comment: @DelightedD0D it does not always return false because if i use if(!optionfucntions.engravingValidation()) first then this conditions works. always the first condition works

Comment: Did you read my answer below and try the logging? Are you saying that if you switch the order of the checks, they both pass?

Comment: Can you confirm that what you want is the two last statements are executed only if both conditions are true? If so, following the @DelightedD0D's hunch, add `console.log(printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation());` and `console.log(optionfucntions.engravingValidation());` before the `if()` then check... Anyway, you might replace all your `if()` block by this more simpler one: `if (!printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation() || !optionfucntions.engravingValidation()) {return false;}`.

Comment: @DelightedD0D You talk about your answer, but it seems to have disappeared!

Comment: @DelightedD0D  Sir please check i have added engravingValidation function code

Comment: @Mehar44 You're overcomplicating the issue! Please first simply log the results and check them.

Comment: @Mehar44 like cFeed mentioned, the actual content of the `engravingValidation()` function isnt relevant, you just need to log the return value so you can actually see it. To cause the problem you're saying you have, that function MUST be returning `false`, there really isnt any other way that the second check would not be executed.

Comment: @cFreed Sorry, I had deleted my answer for a minute while I re-worded part of it. You should see it again now :)

Comment: @Mehar44 You should carefully look at the DelightedD0D's answer below: it clearly analyzes all your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current checks always fail because you are checking for *engraving options* AND *print options* for every product when each product will only have one or the other. This means that every product fails one of the checks. For your checks, you need to first check if the product is a print product or a engraving product.

```
 var isPrintProduct = // do some check to see if is print product
 var isEgravingProduct = // do some check to see if is engraving product
 if(isPrintProduct && !printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation()){
        return false;
 }
 else if(isEgravingProduct && !optionfucntions.engravingValidation()){
        return false;
 }
```

---

#### Original answer

Currently, *BOTH of your attempts are effectively the same*

In both cases, your code will check if `printnameValidation()` returns a falsy value,and if so, you are returning `false` from the event handler and **no further code in the handler is called**.

If `printnameValidation()` returns a truthy value, you go on to check `engravingValidation()`. If that returns a falsy value, you are returning `false` from the event handler and **no further code in the handler is called**.

This means that`engravingValidation()` will only ever be called if `printnameValidation()` evaluates as `true` and `checkDropdownToSetButtonvalue();` will only ever be called if both `printnameValidation()` and `engravingValidation()` both return true.

Since you are returning false, the `else` really doesnt do anything.

If that doesnt answer your question, to help you further, you'll need to explain what exactly your logic *should do*

I have a hunch the real issue might be in `printnameValidation()`. It seems like `printnameValidation()` may be always returning false and you dont realize it. That's the only thing I can see that would cause the second check to never be called.

To debug that, simply add some logging like this (I'd bet the first log is always `false`):

```
console.log(printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation());
console.log(optionfucntions.engravingValidation());
if(!printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation()){
    return false;
}
if(!optionfucntions.engravingValidation()){
    return false;
}
```

---

As @cFreed mentioned, once you work out the 'false' issue, you should refactor your checks to:

`if(!...printnameValidation || !...engravingValidation) return false;`

And as @Pevara mentions, `functions` is misspelled in `printnameoptionfucntions` and `optionfucntions`. You really should fix that too :)

Comment: You're totally right for all points. But may I insist to suggest the more simpler `if(!...printnameValidation || !...engravingValidation)`?

Comment: @cFreed Absolutely! That's exactly how I would write it in fact. (I just didnt want to the OP to think im implying  that that would fix the problem) but yeah, once the real issue is resolved, I would definitely recommend refactoring that (and also the misspelling that Pervara pointed out as well)

Comment: "I just didnt want to the OP to think im implying that that would fix the problem": oh yes, good precaution. I agree.

Comment: I appreciate your help sir. I am going to describe in my question update, the thing i need to accomplish .

Comment: @cFreed can you please check now

Comment: @Mehar44 can you please add the logging mentioned above and tell us what the output is? That will *immediately* tell us if we are right about the return false. Then we can move further, knowing the workflow doesnt help us nearly as much as knowing that return value, that is what is important

Comment: @DelightedD0D you can check the logging in update 2. sorry for adding that late.

Comment: @Mehar44 Wait a minute, are you saying that `.printnameValidation()` should be checked *only* when you have a *product with print option* and `engravingValidation()` should only be checked if you have *product with engraving option*????

Comment: @Mehar44 Thanks for your update. But even with that you must realize that we can't _feel_ all about your issue as you can. So we need to be certain of this: is it correct to say that your `click-)` handle should return `false` if one or both of `printnameValidation()` and `engravingValidation()` returned `false`? And, again, check these results using logging as described by DelightedD0D's answer: __it's _the_ way to reach the solution__.

Comment: @DelightedD0D I had the same suspiscion. But I hope that each of the `...Validation()` functions returns `true` when its checking process is not involved.

Comment: @DelightedD0D yes I want that

Comment: @cFreed Im starting to think that the OP needs something like  `if(isPrintProduct && !printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation()){
        return false;
 }
 else if(isEgravingProduct && !optionfucntions.engravingValidation()){
        return false;
 }`

Comment: @cFreed yep, that's what it is

Comment: @DelightedD0D You might be right... sigh :) I keep thinking it'd be better to take care of this inside the functions. But I see you had the courage to update your answer: hope the OP follows you now...

Comment: @cFreed Agreed, there is almost certainly a much cleaner way to code the whole thing.

Comment: <?php if($engravingStatus){?>
            if(!optionfucntions.engravingValidation()){
                return false;
            }
        <?php } elseif($printnameStatus){?>
            if(!printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation()){
                return false;
            }
        <?php } ?>

Comment: @Mehar44 it seems like you should be able to do the check on the client side, but yeah, that would have the right effect as well, cheers :)

Comment: It would take more time to do the client side check as I don't have much understanding of the code i'm working on plus I had to finish this today.

Comment: Its beacause of you. Thank you sir :)

Comment: @DelightedD0D Congratulations for your perseverance! Great job.

Answer (score 2):

I realy don't understand what you are trying to achieve here, some extra explanation of the desired behavior would be good.

About this snippet though:

```
    if (!printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation()){
        return false;
    }
    else if(!optionfucntions.engravingValidation()){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
```

You have 3 possible exits, that all return false, so you are always gonna get false here. You could just as well have written

```
return false
```

I think you may be looking for [boolean operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) here. I guess you want something like this:

```
if (! printnameoptionfucntions.printnameValidation() || ! optionfucntions.engravingValidation()) {
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Note that the `else` is not nessecary, since that rlast return statement can only be reached when the if evaluated to false.

Also, I noticed that you have `...fucntions...` in your code, shouldn't that be `functions`? I would defenitly change that, even if it is the correct variable name, since that is bound to cause you some headaches if you ever have to edit that code in the future, bugs waiting to happen...